# HAProxy 'Listen' block vs 'frontend/backend' block for load balancing

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, haproxy

I have the following 'listen' proxy block set up and successfully working in HAProxy (for balancing https kubectl access to a kubernetes cluster,  I target **https://k8s.mydomain.com:8383** which load balances to three K8s nodes on port 6443)

```
listen k8s
  bind *:8383
  mode tcp
  option log-health-checks
  timeout client 3h
  timeout server 3h
  server lab11 lab11.mydomain.com:6443 check check-ssl verify none inter 10000
  server lab13 lab13.mydomain.com:6443 check check-ssl verify none inter 10000
  server lab15 lab15.mydomain.com:6443 check check-ssl verify none inter 10000
  balance roundrobin
```

The above works great

But Im trying to set the same configuration up as a 'frontend/backend' style proxy block (below) but it doesnt work (kubectl command returns **“Unable to connect to the server: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client”**)

```
frontend k8s
    mode tcp
    bind *:8383
    default_backend k8s
    timeout client 3h
    timeout server 3h
    option log-health-checks

backend k8s
    server lab11 lab11.mydomain.com:6443 check check-ssl verify none inter 10000
    server lab13 lab13.mydomain.com:6443 check check-ssl verify none inter 10000
    server lab15 lab15.mydomain.com:6443 check check-ssl verify none inter 10000
    balance roundrobin
```

Does anyone have any idea what im doing wrong here? As far as I was aware, I can use a ‘frontend/backend’ proxy block in the same way as 'Listen' … Am i misunderstanding or missing some parameters here to get this working ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try setting `mode tcp` in backend for consistency. not sure, why you use `tcp` there, but probably your backend inherited some default `mode http`. this in turn caused it to make L7 HTTP checks instead of TCP checks. it says it got HTTP response instead of expected HTTPS response. if your servers use SSL then add `ssl` on server lines and then that `verify none` will make sense. or maybe convert frontend and backend explicitely to `mode http`

Comment: Thank you tbielaszewski , adding mode tcp to the backend resolved my issue